# Do you have favourite hole cards - and do these change over time

Tags: texas-hold-em, psychology

Bad as they are, I used to like playing Q8 off/on suit and more recently A & a low number card (say 9 or less) on suit. I know these cards are pretty raggy, but do any of you often find yourselves playing similar duff cards on the back of large/sentimental previous wins?

Comment: My favourite hole cards are AA and KK. I also like winning with 72 sometimes :p

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to try and clean up with 72o sometime...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having favourite hands is more of a goofy thing to do in order to reduce boredom. Many professional players have such favourite hands because they'we been playing for many years and can afford it.

The problem with having something like this is that you immediately lose objectivity. Emotions must be avoided at all costs in the context of poker; having a favourite hand is included in this rule. Poker is something cold and calculated. The only good emotion is some sort of cold, distant empathy, because it can help predict what your opponent(s) will do in the short and medium run.

After many thousands of hands, you will get into situations that will be memorable. That's how the brain is built to work. That's when you'll have the tendency to start loving or hating certain hands. **CRUSH THAT !!** Because it's wrong. That hand was good or bad in that particular context and situation. That's it, nothing more (or you played it wrong :D ). Given that poker does have a luck factor, it only inforces my argument.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of scenarios in which it is more than OK to play hands like Q8o, Q8s, and definitely Axs. There are also plenty of scenarios where you should be folding these hands rather quickly.

Whether or not you do fold them should be completely independent of sentimental wins and losses. Instead, play them or fold them because it is the most profitable option to do so.

tl;dr: No.

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely avoid playing hands because they are "lucky." I used to think KJo was my favorite hand (still gets my blood pumping), but I have learned to *fold these hands for any value other than that they are profitable in a position is poor judgment.
Edit - Spelling error.

Comment: You make a good point. My thing with Q8o/s was that I got something like 3 inside straights in the same tourney once. I'm more inclined to play such favourite hands if I'm losing money. Don't know if this would qualify as "tilt" or where it is just momentary madness...